# PyQt5 Move Button on MainWindow with Drag/Drop

Tags: python, pyqt5

I start to use PyQt5 and I have a question with the usage of mimedata in the example below.

The example allows to move the Button by using the drag/drop event on the MainWindow.

The thing that confuses me is that in the MyButton class that it setups a QmimeData without any data setup and then passes this to the QDrag object directly.

And I did try to remove the QMimedata part and this does make the drag/drop not working anymore which seems like this is a necessary setup.

My question is that what is Qmimedata here in this case?
Because from the description of Qmimedata that it should be no data now then how does it work?

Thanks!

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            return

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        super().mousePressEvent(e)

        if e.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print('press')


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = MyButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 180, 331, 151))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Move it"))



class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super().__init__(parent)
      self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)

      self.setAcceptDrops(True)



    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.pos()
        self.ui.pushButton.move(position)

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()





apps = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
ex.show()
apps.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to use the code created from `pyuic`, which is *not* supposed to be edited nor "imitated": it's *compiled* code that should be left as it is, and used from your actual code written in different file(s), as explained [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Anyhow, the most important part is to understand how Qt's drag&drop implementation works. I'd suggest you to carefully read the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html): while it's written for C++ developers, the concepts are the same. It could seem overwhelming and somehow overcomplicated, but there's plenty of serious and good reasons for which it works like that.

Basically, when a drag object is created it *has* to have some data attached to it, otherwise no application (including your own) would know what to do with it. For this use case, you'll need at least two things:

- what kind of "data" the drag object contains, otherwise one could drag any kind of object in your application (for example, the user is dragging an image and releases the mouse button on your window by mistake), and if you don't check for that you'll get your button moved even if the user didn't want to.
- what widget you're going to move (there's just one widget in your case, but that might change in the future)

This is done by attaching some data to the QDrag object, which is set in MIME format. Since this is a specific case (see [QMimeData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html) documentation for standard types provided by Qt), you'll need to create your own mimeData format and provide some data. In order to do that, you'll need a QByteArray and a QDataStream set in write mode to the array, which will be used to write the actual data the drag object needs.

After the drag object has been created and "executed", you'll need to ensure that the receiver dragEnterEvent's event actually contains the MIME format you're interested in actually exists in the event's mimeData, so that you can read its data and actually do something useful with it.

I've created a very basic example that allows you to use drag&drop to move the button the interface, but be aware that this has serious implications: in this case there's only one parent widget (the `centralWidget`), but if you are going to use some more complex layout, possibly by using frames or groupboxes, it won't work. Adding a widget to a child of the main widget will make that latter a parent of the former, which will make its position relative to the parent position.
For example, let's say you've created a layout with two group boxes, and you've added your button to the second one. In that case, you'll not be able to easily move it to the first box unless you reparent it, and if you try to move within the second one (where it already is) you'll need to compute its final position according to that box, as long as you're catching the dropEvent in the main window. Even more: if you've some complex layout (with nested widgets and layouts), you'll need to find a way to get the actual widget you're dragging into.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print('press')
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            # save the click position to keep it consistent when dragging
            self.mousePos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            return
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        # create a byte array and a stream that is used to write into
        byteArray = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(byteArray, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        # set the objectName and click position to keep track of the widget
        # that we're moving and it's click position to ensure that it will
        # be moved accordingly
        stream.writeQString(self.objectName())
        stream.writeQVariant(self.mousePos)
        # create a custom mimeData format to save the drag info
        mimeData.setData('myApp/QtWidget', byteArray)
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        # add a pixmap of the widget to show what's actually moving
        drag.setPixmap(self.grab())
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        # set the hotspot according to the mouse press position
        drag.setHotSpot(self.mousePos - self.rect().topLeft())
        drag.exec_()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.pushButton = MyButton(centralWidget, objectName='pushButton')
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 180, 331, 151))
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        # only accept our mimeData format, ignoring any other data content
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('myApp/QtWidget'):
            event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(event.mimeData().data('myApp/QtWidget'))
        # QDataStream objects should be read in the same order as they were written
        objectName = stream.readQString()
        # find the child widget that has the objectName set within the drag event
        widget = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QWidget, objectName)
        if not widget:
            return
        # move the widget relative to the original mouse position, so that
        # it will be placed exactly where the user drags it and according to
        # the original click position
        widget.move(event.pos() - stream.readQVariant())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Really thanks for the detailed reply. And yes, the Qmimiedata in the example I provided was confusing me a lot since there is no data addressed. After reading your explanation that gives me a more completed picture of using this which I will need to create a custom mimedata type. Thanks again!